# setting displayedValue of dojo TimeTextBox doesnt work as expected on 9.0.1 Domino Server

Tags: dojo, xpages, xpages-extlib

I have a TimeTextBox that worked just fine on a 8.5.3 Server running on Windows but as soon as push the database to a 9.0.1 Server running on Linux the displayedValue only works in Chrome but leaves the input field empty when I use Firefox or Internet Explorer.

```
<xp:dateTimeHelper dojoType="dijit.form.TimeTextBox" id="dateTimeHelperEndTime">
  <xp:this.dojoAttributes>
    <xp:dojoAttribute name="displayedValue">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return '17:30';}]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:dojoAttribute>
    <xp:dojoAttribute name="constraints" 
        value="{timePattern: 'HH:mm'}">
    </xp:dojoAttribute>
  </xp:this.dojoAttributes>
</xp:dateTimeHelper>
```

Did anybody have a similiar problem after putting an Xpage Application on a new Server?

Answer (score 0):

I have not had this problem. But a quick test is to change the compiled version of the application to 853 and change the dojo version to the version in 853, which is I think 1.6.1